# DNN Notifications API

Tags: list, notifications, dotnetnuke-6

I am using DNN 6.2 and trying to create a notification but do not understand the API very well as I am a novice.

the documentation suggests the following

```
    NotificationsController.Instance.SendNotification(
  notification, 
  PortalSettings.PortalId,
  new List<RoleInfo>(), // Pass here the list of roles or null if the notification is going to be sent to individual users only.
  new List<UserInfo>(), // Pass here the list of users or null if the notification is going to be sent to roles only.
); // There is an overload that doesn't receive this parameter and uses Admin as sender.
```

I have a list already defined and populated with userIds

```
private List<string> listOfFriends = new List<string>();
```

So I though the following would work

```
NotificationsController.Instance.SendNotification(notification, PortalSettings.PortalId,"", listOfFriends);
```

But I am getting an error 'has some invalid arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working?

I think this

```
NotificationsController.Instance.SendNotification(notification, PortalSettings.PortalId,"", listOfFriends);
```

should be

```
NotificationsController.Instance.SendNotification(notification, PortalSettings.PortalId, **null**, listOfFriends);
```